# PHP5-Curl install error no installation candidate

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, debian

I want to install `PHP5-Curl` in my Debian server. But when I run this command:

```
apt-get install PHP5-Curl
```

I got an error like:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

Package PHP5-Curl is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'PHP5-Curl' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: This could be due to a mix of versions. Please check if there is a package `php5-curl` available at all in your configured repositories first. If so, then check the versions of your php5 packages, they should all come from the same repository.

Comment: You can tell exactly what I can do?

Comment: Did you add the repository ?

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5`

Comment: Ahh :( , shows `-bash: add-apt-repository: command not found`

Comment: This is more of a sysop question, not a programming / PHP question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl`

Answer (score 12):

Try searching for the available version that suits for you with `sudo apt-cache search curl | grep php` and then `sudo apt-get install php<x>-curl`.

In my case it was `php7.0-curl`.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer, not the one above (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34574887/php5-curl-install-error-no-installation-candidate/42048947#42048947). `5.6` is out of date, as is `7.0`. This solution gave me the ability to find the correct value `7.2`, which I'm sure will change in the next few months.

Comment: This really worked for me, i had installed Curl 7.2 yet i was still running php 5.6

So i upgraded my php to 7.2 and the error was sorted.

Thanks.....

Comment: Thank you! And do not forget to do `sudo service apache2 restart` afterwards :D

Answer (score 1):

First search for your php version using command php -v and then download the respective version of php(version)-curl.

Answer (score -5):

It looks like you have multiple, conflicting versions of PHP installed. First, let's clean up. Back up your configuration files first, as this will remove them.

```
dpkg --purge --force-all php5-curl
apt-get remove php5-*
apt-get purge php5-*
apt-get autoremove
```

Now, run `dpkg -l | grep php5` again, and make sure that no `php5-...` packages are installed.

Then, let's start fresh:

```
apt-get install php5-cli php5-curl
```

If you need the Apache module:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

Or if you need the FPM module:

```
apt-get install php5-fpm
```

Comment: What does `apt-cache rdepends PHP5-Curl` give you?

Comment: You can see from the OPs posted messages that `apt-get` handles cases correctly.

Comment: Ok what about `apt-cache rdepends php5-curl`? :) And perhaps add the output of `dpkg -l | grep php` to your post above.

Comment: Same result shows <php5-curl>  .  and when i run `dpkg -l | grep php` shows `packages built from the php5 source
rc  php5-curl                                5.3.10-1ubuntu3.21            amd64        CURL module for php5
ii  php5-dev                                 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4           amd64        Files for PHP5 module development
`

Comment: Ok, now we have some clarity! You have conflicting versions of PHP installed. I will edit my answer, just a sec.

Comment: Ok, try now! If you see any problems or errors post them.

Comment: First command `apt-get remove php5-*` shows `E: Unable to locate package php5-curl_5.3.10-1ubuntu3.21_amd64.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php5-curl_5.3.10-1ubuntu3.21_amd64.deb'`

Comment: Edited again. Use `dpkg --purge --force-all php5-curl`.

Comment: Thank you for answers . but i run this command `dpkg --purge --force-all php5-curl` shows `dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove php5-curl which isn't installed` . and when i run `apt-get remove php5-*` i get same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99585/discussion-between-will-and-amirali-roshanaei).

Comment: Thats great, I just tried all the steps above and the final step is "continue in chat" Thank you very much.